# splitting variable array in string elements in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split

I have created a variable with the first 4 letters of my sample names, but when I try to pass this variable in a for loop it fails.

```
my_sample=$(find ~/myfolder -type f -name ".bam" | awk -F '.bam' '{print $1}' | awk -F '/normal/' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)
```

I obtained this

```
mysample = sample1 sample2 sample3...sampleN
```

But when I execute this (I need to cycle using numbers and not element names)

```bash
for ((i=0;i<${#my_sample[@]};i++)); do
```

It considers the first iteration as the whole my_sample (i=sample1 sample2 sample3...sampleN) but I want that the first iteration is sample1, the second sample2 and so on.

If I try

```
a=( $my_sample )
```

This give me only the first name

```
sample1
```

Someone could help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have GNU tools, you can use NUL delimiters rather than newline delimiters and this all becomes very moot.

Comment: That said -- `readarray -t my_sample < <(...)`

Comment: That said, `a=( $my_sample )` _does_ generate an array, even if it's buggy (and it [_is in fact_ buggy](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29)). How were you checking its contents? Use `declare -p a` to print an unambiguous representation of the variable. If you refer to `"$a"` instead of `"${a[@]}"`, that'll only refer to the first element.

Comment: BTW, consider `for i in "${!my_sample[@]}"; do` -- that's not just shorter, it also works if your array has sparse indices. (Let's say you run `a=( zero one two three ); unset 'a[0]'` -- then the first element in array `a` has index `1`, not `0`, so unconditionally iterating starting from zero is incorrect; bash's "arrays" are really numerically-indexed maps, not what other languages call arrays).